# How to write the path to my css file in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, twig

Sorry for this question, but I don't remeber how exactly the paths were written, so please help me to specify my path.

My base template where I want to specify the path to the css file is here (if it is a good idea to add the path to the css file in the base template at all):

`Project/app/Resources/views/base.html.twig`

And the css file is here:

`Project\src\Acme\MyBundle\Resources\public\css\style.css`

I also run `assets:install` so the css file is here too:

`Project\web\bundles\acmemybundle\css\style.css`

So my question is to where to give the path in `base.html.twig` (to the web folder or to the folder in my bundle) and how exactly to write it:

```
<link href="{{ asset('path') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: It should be the path relative to the web directory: `{{ asset('bundles/acmemybundle/css/style.css') }}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normal link:

```
<link href="{{ asset('bundles/acmemybundle/css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

If you want to apply `cssrewrite` filter:

```
{% stylesheets filter='cssrewrite'
  'bundles/acmemybundle/css/style.css'      
 %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" media="screen" />      
{% endstylesheets %}
```

If you want to apply `compress` filter

```
{% stylesheets filter='?yui_css'
  '@AcmeMyBundle/Resources/public/css/style.css'      
 %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" media="screen" />      
{% endstylesheets %}
```